# Array to string conversion what is error please suggest me

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get error Array to string conversion
my controller is

```
function index() {
        if ($this->input->post('submit') != NULL) {
            $data = array();
            $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
            $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
            $result['data'] = $this->Useraccount_mod->getUser_list($data);
            $data['userlist'] = $result['data'];
            $this->load->view('Useraccount/Userlist', $data);
        } else {
               $data = array();
            $result['data'] = $this->Useraccount_mod->getUser_list($data);
            $data['userlist'] = $result['data'];
            $this->load->view('Useraccount/Userlist', $data);
        }
    }
```

And model

```
 function getUser_list($data) {
        if ($data) {
            $this->db->like('username',$data);
            $this->db->like('name',$data);
            $query = $this->db->get('users');
            return $query->result_array();

        } else {
            $query = $this->db->get("users");
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }
```

where I am wrong? Please suggest me

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php
>
> Line Number: 980
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ov400\application\models\Useraccount_mod.php
>   Line: 31 Function: like
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ov400\application\controllers\Users.php Line: 23
>   Function: getUser_list
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ov400\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to provide the Array as Information in your "like". Please try this:

```
 function getUser_list($data) {
    if ($data) {
        $this->db->like('username',$data['username']);
        $this->db->like('name',$data['name']);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result_array();

    } else {
        $query = $this->db->get("users");
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```